# merge "numpy.int64" and "pandas.core.series.Series"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes on a key column.
However,

```
>>>type(df1.key[0])
numpy.int64
```

and

```
>>>type(df2.key[0])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

This causes an error message of

```
"You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns"
```

I tried to run this before the merge()

```
    pd1.key.astype(int)
    pd2.key.astype(int)
```

but it does not work and the error message remains...

Comment: Could you please show a couple of rows and columns of both data frames you want to merge?

Comment: Are you assigning the value of astype to the original dataframe? `pd1 = pd1.key.astype(int)` and `pd2 = pd2.key.astype(int)` and then merging? If you do not wish to alter the original dataframe, you could also use `pd3 = pd3.key.astype(int, copy=True)` and `pd4 = pd2.key.astype(int, copy=True)` and then merge `pd3` and `pd4`.